# View Controller Containment with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

my app is navigation based, i am adding a child view controller to one of my screens like so :

```
    [self addChildViewController:_settingsVc];
[_settingsVc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:_settingsVc.view];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:_settingsVc.view
                  duration:0.6
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    _header_view.header_title.text = @"Settings";
                }];
```

the view and animation shows great! and when i am returning like so from the presented child view controller :

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:_settingsVc.view toView:self.view
                  duration:0.6
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    _header_view.header_title.text = @"Friends Locator";
                }];
```

i goes well too... the problem is if i am entering to the child view controller and hit the back button of the `UINavigationBar` then i can see the bar slides out and i got black screen.
how can i manage this?

Comment: add this option also UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions. i.e options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft|UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions

Comment: dosent do a thing different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button is do UINavigationController pop animation. You can try add a leftBarButtonItem that set a customView which is a UIButton, and add your own back animation in the button click event.